# Create entity in Breeze relying on other entity

Tags: javascript, breeze, durandal

I'm working my way with BreezeJS in combination with Durandal. This all works fine but I have a question about creating a new entity that has a relation with another entity.

Lets say we have an entity customer and order. When I create a new order which relies on customer it has 2 fields one for customerID and one for Customer it self! The customerID is given correctly but it crashes for not having a Customer object! How do I solve this?

My Dataservice.createT is:

```
 // This function creates an entity for the specific table (entity)
        // that is passed as an parameter. The entity is the same as the table name 
        //in the map folders. So for creating a new Memo entity should be tblMemo
        Dataservice.prototype.createT = function (initialValues, entity) {
            return this.manager.createEntity(entity, initialValues);
        };



var repairOrderLineN = dataservice.createT({
                        RepairOrderID: '1', CustomerID: result[0].CustomerId,
                        Description: result[0].Description, InternalCode: result[0].Code,
                        Hours: result[0].Hours, Tariff: result[0].Tariff,
                        Costs: result[0].Costs, Quantity: result[0].Qty,
                        DamageCode: result[0].Dam, RepairCode: result[0].Rep,
                        MaterialCode: result[0].Mat, LocationCode: result[0].Location,
                        IsAgreement: result[0].IsAgreement, IsAuthorized: result[0].IsAuthorized,
                        DoRepair: result[0].DoRepair
                    }, 'tblRepairOrderLine');

                    if (repairOrderLineN.entityAspect.validateEntity()) {
                        extendItem(repairOrderLineN);
                        repairorderlines.push(new repairorderline(repairOrderLineN));
                        dataservice.saveChanges();
                        updateFinance();
                    }
```

A JSON is given from a modal to create the entity and off course I understand the customer object isn't in it! damn i'm lost :S Help :(

Answer (score 0):

I need more information about your case and specifically what you mean by "crashes".

I don't know what your `dataservice.createT` does. It's actually a little too complex for easy answer here. Can you simplify a test case for us?

Meanwhile, here is a passing test that I'm adding to "*entityTests.js*" of the [DocCode sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/doccode) that demonstrates your scenario with Northwind.

```
 /*********************************************************
 * Add an Order with initializer that set its parent Customer by Id
 *********************************************************/
 test("add Customer created using initializer with parent Customer Id", 4, function () {
     var em = newEm();

     // create a new parent Customer
     var parentCustomer = em.createEntity("Customer", {
          CustomerID: breeze.core.getUuid(),
          CompanyName: 'TestCo'
     });

     // a new Order which is a child of the parent Customer
     var newOrder = em.createEntity("Order", { CustomerID: parentCustomer.CustomerID() });

     ok(newOrder.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded(), "newOrder should be 'added'");
     ok(parentCustomer.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded(), "parentCustomer should be 'added'");

     var orderCustomer = newOrder.Customer();
     ok(orderCustomer, "newOrder's parent 'Customer' property should return a Customer entity");
     ok(orderCustomer === parentCustomer,
         "newOrder's parent Customer should be " + parentCustomer.CompanyName());
 });
```

It would work just as well if the parent Customer previously existed (e.g., had been fetched).

Btw, I had to initialize `parentCustomer.CustomerID` because it is defined in metadata as a client-generated key. In most of our examples, the entity key is store-generated (e.g., `Order.OrderID`) and would not be specified.

### Update 4/30/2013

I suspect that somewhere in your initializer object is a `result[0].something` where **`something`** is an entity rather than **a simple data value** (e.g,. an integer `id`).

As I write, the `createEntity` blows up if any initializer value is a Breeze entity. That will be fixed in v.1.3.2 which should be out soon. Note that this new feature will be beta at first. The API won't change but there are many edge conditions and it's hard to cover them all. It will take time to drive out lingering bugs.

No matter what, you have alternatives today. You would be fine if you just initialized using the foreign key ids for the related entities instead of initializing with the related entities themselves.  Or you could assign the related entities *after first* creating the entity as in:

```
...
  var thing = manager.createEntity('Thing', {
        ... initialize with simple data values
      }

  var thing.relatedEntityA = relatedEntityA;
  var thing.relatedEntityB = relatedEntityB;

...
```

Comment: can you provide us with a working sample instead of the address to the test.

when creating a new Complex entity we dont know what would be the initiated value because user is just creating it.

for example to create a new entity of type "thing" (in your example)  what would be the initialized value?

i had so many problem creating a new entity which has some other complex properties. and it is not easy.....

Comment: **The test is a working example.**  I don't what you're asking for.

Comment: Then there is the matter of not knowing the property values at the time you create a thing. That is usually no problem if the unknowns are allowed to stay unknown for a while. If they must be known before you create the entity, then you'll have to work with an "item view model" first ... a custom structure that can accumulate the facts that you require before you can instantiate an entity. But I suspect we are not on the same page. If you want more help, you must give us the smallest example that still cuts to the heart of your problem.